# Dotted slur and two lyric stanzas with different amount of syllables

Tags: notation, lilypond, slurs

I have the following problem with two lyric stanzas for one voice, that have different syllables. The following example works with using an underscore at the end.

```
\version "2.18.2"

\paper {
  ragged-last = ##f
}

\score {
  <<
    \new Voice = "melodie"
    \relative c ' {
      c d e f |
      \slurDotted
      g2 g |
    }
    \new Lyrics  \lyricsto "melodie"
    \lyricmode { 
      <<
      { one two three four five _   }
      \new Lyrics {
        two three four five sev -- en
      }
      >>
    }
  >>
}
```

But if now I want to add a dotted slur to `g2 g` it is not working anymore.
I know that technically the correct usage would be a tie not a slur, but I did not find an option to dott a tie.
[image: example only working without slur]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further research and I found [a quite simple way](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/stanzas#stanzas-with-different-rhythms) in the lilypond docs and applied it.

```
\score {
  \new Staff
  <<
    \new Voice = "melodie"
    \relative c' {
      c d e f |
      \slurDotted
      g2( g) |
      a4
    }
    \new Lyrics  \lyricsto "melodie"
    \lyricmode {
      \set stanza = "1."
      one two three four five six
    }
    \new Lyrics  \lyricsto "melodie"
    \lyricmode {
      \set stanza = "2."
      two three four five
      \set ignoreMelismata = ##t
      sev -- en
      \unset ignoreMelismata
      eight
    }
  >>
}
```

[image: this is my way]

Answer (score 2):

None of the syllables for stanzas 1 and 2 line up correctly in @nath's workaround, because the horizontal spacing of the "hidden" notes in voice two is the same as if they were *not* hidden.

A better fix is not to use voice two, and simply assign both sets of lyrics to the same voice "melodie".

You can switch off the side-effect of the slur in automatically creating a melisma between the slurred notes. You then need to add a dummy "blank" lyric in stanza 1 for the second tied note.

I added an extra note to the OP's example to show that more clearly.

```
\score {
  \new Staff
  <<
    \new Voice = "melodie"
    \relative c' {
      c d e f |
      \slurDotted
      \set melismaBusyProperties = #'()
      g2( g) |
      \unset melismaBusyProperties
      a4
    }
    \new Lyrics  \lyricsto "melodie"
    \lyricmode {
      \set stanza = "1."
      one two three four five " " six
    }
    \new Lyrics  \lyricsto "melodie"
    \lyricmode {
      \set stanza = "2."
      two three four five sev -- en eight
    }
  >>
}
```

The apparent misalignment of the syllables "five" and "sev(en)" is actually correct, though it looks a bit strange. According to standard texts on music notation, a syllable sung to a single note should be centered under the note, but a syllable sung to several notes should be left-justified under the first note, which is what Lilypond does here.

[image]